# generate random binary number in perl

Tags: perl, random

I want to generate 64 iteration of non-repetitive 6 digits that only consist of 0 and 1 (eg. 111111, 101111, 000000) by using perl.
I found code that can generate random hex and try to modify it but I think my code is all wrong. This is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %a;

foreach (1 .. 64) {
    my $r;
    do {
        $r = int(rand(2));
    }
until (!exists($a{$r}));
printf "%06d\n", $r;
$a{$r}++;
}
```

Comment: What are you using your random numbers for? Because you should note - perl random is not 'strong', so is unsuitable for anything security related.

Comment: I am actually want to generate all possible 6-bit binary number. Since writing all the possible combination by hand is cumbersome and prone to human error, I think it will be good idea to just generate it by using rand() with no repetition and store it into array.

Comment: That's a very inefficient approach. Why not just count from 0 to 63 and print it in binary?

Comment: I forgot that I actually can print in binary format using `printf`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 64 x 6-bit integers you can call `int(rand(64));` 64 times, there's no need to generate each bit separately.

Your code can be modified to work like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# your code goes here

use strict;
use warnings;

my %a;

foreach (1 .. 64) {
    my $r;
    do
    {
        $r = int(rand(64));
    } until (!exists($a{$r}));
    printf "%06b\n", $r;
    $a{$r}++;
}
```

The results are stored in a array of integers. The `%06b` format specifier string prints out a 6 bit binary number.

Comment: Thanks!. Does your code will generate repetitive random number?

Comment: I've edited the code to avoid duplicates, I didn't notice that requirement at first. I think the other answer is actually better if that is the goal, but I'll leave this answer here to show how your existing code could be changed to make it work.

Comment: Thank you very much. One more thing. Can you explain `printf "%06b\n"`. I am not sure `%b` is use for.

Comment: It's used for formatting a number in binary. %d is for decimal, %b is for binary

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean that you want 64 six-bit numbers, all distinct from each other?  If so, then you should just shuffle the list `(0, 1, 2, 3, …, 63)`, because there are exactly 64 six-bit numbers — you just want them in a random order.

And if you want to print them as base-two string, use the `%06b` format.

```
use List::Util;

my @list = List::Util::shuffle 0..63;
printf "%06b\n", $_ for @list;
```

Answer (score 3):

From the comments:

> I am actually want to generate all possible 6-bit binary number. Since writing all the possible combination by hand is cumbersome and prone to human error, I think it will be good idea to just generate it by using rand() with no repetition and store it into array.

This is a horribly inefficent approach to take, thanks to random number collisons.

You get the same result with:

```
printf ( "%06b\n", $_ ) for 1..63;
```

If you're after a random order (although, you don't seem to suggest that you do):

```
use List::Util qw ( shuffle ); 
printf ( "%06b\n", $_ ) for shuffle (0..63);
```